# Class property not set by function

Tags: matlab, class, properties

I am using MATLAB classes and experience a problem with properties.

The code I call is

```
theory = ODtheory;
theory.enableDebug(true);
theory.captureRange();
```

The last function should print out values since the debug is set to `true`

This is the code for the class:

```
    function obj = ODtheory(~)
        obj.isDebug = false;
    end
    
    function obj = enableDebug(obj,value)
        obj.isDebug = value;
    end
```

But in `function range = captureRange(obj)` the variable (property) `obj.isDebug` is still set to false.

```
function range = captureRange(obj)
   ...
   if obj.isDebug; disp(['FOW: ' num2str(round(FOW,1)) '/mm']); end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `ODtheory` class is a [value class](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html), so you need to assign it back to itself to register the change of the object properties.

For example:

```
theory = ODtheory;
theory = theory.enableDebug(true);
theory.captureRange();
```

If your `captureRange` function also modifies object properties, you should also call that with

```
theory = theory.captureRange();
```

An alternative would be to make the class a `handle` class (see the above link)

```
classdef ODtheory < handle
%  ... class definition here ...
end
```

Then you could use your original code without the assignments.